# Get post object from mention PRAW reddit api

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I cannot for the life of me gather the post object using PRAW v7.1 (reddit api) in python.

I saw old articles online that use `get_comment()` but this is not in the 7.1 version as far as I can tell.

Here's my goal, I wish to make a bot that answers mentions in order to repost a post on another subreddit when someone mentions it in the comments, and of course answer the comment.

Here's what I got so far

```py
import praw


def main():
    r = praw.Reddit(
        client_id='##CENSORED##',
        client_secret='##CENSORED##',
        password='##CENSORED##',
 
    i = r.inbox.mentions()

    for f in i:
        print(f, dir(f), type(f))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This indeed outputs the mention object i.e. the comment. I can view the comment's body by looking at `f.body`, but when looking at the `f.parent`, or `f.context`, I cannot find the original post object.

I known there is not much in my code, but I looked at most of the output from `dir(f)`, and at the readthedoc and can't do it.

What am I missing?

Comment: fiy, I think reddit is having issues right now, i'm having `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002]`. Or maybe I've just reached some quato limits ith my trials,

Comment: Is no one having this issue? What am I missing?